# Deployment steps takes much time

Tags: sharepoint

I develop a sharepoint project on win 7. My computer has 4 GB of RAM and a powerfull processor. But deployment steps take too much time. In total it takes about 7 minutes to deploy the solution.

Somebody knows, in what there can be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

What is your Windows Experience Index for your computer?  (Click start - type "Windows Experience Index", then run the assessment)  Please list all of the numbers.

That can help you identify what parts of your system might be slow.  If it's your disk (which is likely - it's often a bottleneck, especially for Sharepoint), you run Sharepoint off an SSD.

You can try to turn some of the Sharepoint services off from central administration (if you're running everything including search, Visio services, Excel services, etc., but you're not using them, it can help to turn off the ones you're not using).

What other applications do you have running on the computer?  What other services are running on the computer?  You can try turning some off to see if it helps to speed things up.

Comment: The problem was with accounts. I worked under local account and my compute was in domain account. I had to disconnect from net to speed up deployment.